# ffmpeg error: "Missing ')' or too many args in 'if(gt(a,1),650,-1)'"

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, scale

I am trying to run this ffmpeg command in linux shell, to scale down the video (if portrait, than to maximum height of 650, while adjusting the width. And if landscape, then 650 maximum width, and adjust the height with aspect ratio):

`ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -r 30 -vf scale="'if(gt(a,1),650,-1)':'if(gt(a,1),-1,650)'" -vcodec libx264 output_file1.mp4`

But I get the following error:

> [scale @ 0x1d48a40] [Eval @ 0x7fff53a49340] Missing ')' or too many
>   args in 'if(gt(a,1),650,-1)' [scale @ 0x1d48a40] [Eval @
>   0x7fff53a49340] Missing ')' or too many args in 'if(gt(a,1),-1,650)'
>   Error when evaluating the expression 'if(gt(a,1),-1,650)'

**EDIT: I have tried using the new @slhck syntax:

```
-vf "scale=if(gt(a\,1)\,650\,-2):if(gt(a\,1)\,-2\,650)"
```

The result I got was:

> ffmpeg version 0.8.16-4:0.8.16-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c)
>   2000-2014 the Libav developers   built on Sep 16 2014 18:33:49 with
>   gcc 4.6.3 The ffmpeg program is only provided for script compatibility
>   and will be removed in a future release. It has been deprecated in the
>   Libav project to allow for incompatible command line syntax
>   improvements in its replacement called avconv (see Changelog for
>   details). Please use avconv instead.
>
> Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate:
>   180000.00 (180000/1) -> 90000.00 (180000/2) Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1.mp4':   Metadata:
>       major_brand     : isom
>       minor_version   : 0
>       compatible_brands: isom3gp4
>       creation_time   : 2015-02-05 14:54:24   Duration: 00:00:45.30, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17058 kb/s
>       Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 17021 kb/s, 30.01 fps, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
>       Metadata:
>         creation_time   : 2015-02-05 14:54:24
>       Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 124 kb/s
>       Metadata:
>         creation_time   : 2015-02-05 14:54:24 File 'output_file1.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
>
> **[buffer @ 0x747ec0] w:1920 h:1080 pixfmt:yuv420p  [scale @ 0x745a40] [Eval @ 0x7fffac94b220] Missing ')' or too many args in
>   'if(gt(a,1),650,-2)'  [scale @ 0x745a40] [Eval @ 0x7fffac94b220]
>   Missing ')' or too many args in 'if(gt(a,1),-2,650)' Error when
>   evaluating the expression 'if(gt(a,1),-2,650)'  Error opening
>   filters!**

What should I do?

Comment: Please show the full, uncut command line output, too, and mention which shell you're using.

Comment: I have edited the questions, and added the full output, after trying @slhck syntax. The shell I am using is Putty session connected to my AWS EC2 linux server.

Comment: You're using a broken and old version of ffmpeg released under the wrong name by the Libav fork. So in essence it's a fake. Please use a real, recent version, which you can download from http://ffmpeg.org/download.html — choose a static build if you want the easy way without installation.

Comment: Thank you very much! How should I install it? Or use the static build?

Comment: I have installed ffmpeg according to this guide: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu. Which supposed to be the newest version of ffmpeg isn't it? How can it be my version is old?

Comment: Your version is so old because the Ubuntu maintainers switched from FFmpeg to Libav, and Libav initially supplied an old version for the repos. As the message in your log output says, this version has been deprecated in favor of the "real" `avconv` from Libav. But an `apt-get install ffmpeg` will never really give you a recent version on any system because it takes time to propagate them.

Answer (score 4):

Well, first of all this won't work as the height/width must be divisible by 2 for libx264, and so you need to put `-2` instead of `-1` as the height/width argument. See the [scale video filter documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) for more info about that.

Another problem: Your ffmpeg is quite outdated and may not support the filter expression you're trying to use. [Download a recent static build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) or [compile it yourself](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

For the expression to work you must [escape](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Quoting-and-escaping) the commas:

```
-vf "scale=if(gt(a\,1)\,650\,-2):if(gt(a\,1)\,-2\,650)"
```

Or put it in single quotes:

```
-vf scale="'if(gt(a,1),650,-2)':'if(gt(a,1),-2,650)'"
```

As the latter is what you're already using, perhaps try the first variant with escaping.